# Cannot Init Late Binding Knockout

Tags: knockout.js

I have main view model which has sub models these are used on same page. I want to load some hidden sub view when button click. Bu it's not working like that:

```
function mainViewModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.moduleIn = createSubViewModel(moduleViewModel);
        self.module1 = ko.observable();

        // this module will loaded after menu click
        self.loadModule1 = function() {
           // create only first attempt
           if (typeof self.module1 == 'function') {
                 self.module1 = createSubViewModel(module1ViewModel);
           }
        }
}

ko.applyBindings(new mainViewModel);
```

Here is action button

```
<div data-bind="click: loadModule1.bind($data)">Module 1</div>
```

My goal is fill this view, but no change in it?

```
<div  data-bind="with: module1">
...
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide us with the full source, preferably in form of a working JSFiddle example. Also, do you see any errors in your browsers console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**module1** is an observable so you have to set it appropriately, you were overriding it.

```
function mainViewModel() {

        var self = this;

        self.moduleIn = createSubViewModel(moduleViewModel);
        self.module1 = ko.observable();

        // this module will loaded after menu click
        self.loadModule1 = function() {
           // create only first attempt
           if (typeof self.module1 == 'function') {
                // setting module1
                 self.module1(createSubViewModel(module1ViewModel));
           }
        }
}
```

Also not sure what you were trying to accomplish with **data-bind="click: loadModule1.bind($data)"**. You can just bind loadModule1 to the click event.

```
<div data-bind="click: loadModule1">Module 1</div>


<div  data-bind="with: module1">
...
</div>
```